# How can I set a keyboard shortcut to switch between Excel tabs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

I find the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>PgDn</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd>not good enough. When I have a lot of tabs it's very annoying to get to the right tab, or move it and change the order, which is sometimes important.

I need Excel to switch between the current tab and the previous tab I worked with - regardless of their physical order. Just like windows <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> .

I guess I can build a macro that remembers my last tab and assign a shortcut to it, but I would like to know if Excel already comes with that functionality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe Excel has a keyboard shortcut for toggling between sheets. In Excel 2007 & 2010, as a non-VBA workaround, you can create a window for each sheet that you're working on.

#### How..

Let's say you were working on **Sheet1** and **Sheet10**.

1. Select **Sheet10** and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>. This creates another window where **Sheet10** is active. Note that at the top of the window, the file name now has a `:2` after it, like so:

   [image]
2. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to the first window, and highlight **Sheet1**. Note that the first window now has a `:1` after the file name at the top.

   [image]

You can just use good old <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back and forth between the two sheets.

Note that you're not creating another instance of Excel, just a separate view for each sheet you need. So you can still add cell references, and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in either window updates the file. If you want to work on another sheet, either change the active worksheet on one of the windows, or spawn another one.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> closes a window.

Comment: You are smart ...I've read so many books and somehow... the message didn't pass :) thank you very much.

Comment: +1 + to combine , if you are on Windows 7 or 8 you could also press WinLog + <<Num>> , where <<Num>> is the number of the pinned application on the taskbar ..

Answer (score 3):

Pressing CTRL+G will allow you to type in the tab & cell number you want to go to. For example, in Kaze's example spreadsheet above, if you start with the "Sheet10" tab selected, you can press CTRL+G, and in the window that pops up, type the following:

'Sheet9'!A1

Press "OK", and it will bring you to that sheet & cell. After you've done that once, you can simply double-click the recent links you've gone to, instead of typing in the whole link.

Comment: Actually I think your answer is the best one providing one has first named the tables : http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/rename-an-excel-table-HA010223129.aspx. - e.g. select table Alt , JT , A , type the name of the table ... After this Ctrl + G , type <<TableName>> , hit Enter ... - much faster than the Ctrl + PageDown  , Ctrl + PgUp

Comment: But (Ctrl)+(Page), (Alt)+(Tab), and (right-click) → "Activate" all remember your current position on the sheet — and even if you have cells selected.  This answer requires that you remember where you were, or at least can specify what cell you want to go to.  This could be very disruptive of work flow.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to navigate between worksheets in Excel.

You can also right-click on the navigation arrows in the lower left-hand corner to display an Activate menu from which you can choose a worksheet.

Comment: I think he said in the question that he knows that and it is not good enough .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the excellent question and the excellent answers ! I am still amazed of the amount of hidden functionalities accessible only for the truly PRO users ...

Actually My answer is a complimentary one to the answer of Ethan with one major addition. I realize to late after the 5 minutes of the expiration for comments that my comment was not fully explained , thus:

Select first each table in the sheets ( Ctrl + Shift + Down , Ctrl + Shift + Left ) , format it as table tables ( Home , Format as table ) and named it according to this instruction http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/rename-an-excel-table-HA010223129.aspx. - e.g select table Alt , JT , A , type the name of the table ...

Now enjoy: Ctrl + G , type <> , hit Enter ..- excel will jump to the <> you have predifined , much faster than the Ctrl + PageDown  , Ctrl + PgUp and much more intuitive in my opinion than the "New Window" approach.